How to test Keychron K3 Pro PCB LEDs
After plugging Keychron K3 Pro keyboard to USB port on Tesmart KVM switch (used not original power adapter maybe it worked not stable), after 10 min of working keyboard and mouse unplugged and light off.
After replug it directly to PC, both start to work, but keyboard backlight works only on upper half rows (it has 6 horizontal rows of keys and highlight only on upper 3 rows).
Re-flashing firmware, plugging into few PCs etc. — nothing helps. Then I disassembled it and test all LED diodes with 5 V DC (pins on ESP32) — all LEDs — work, then I test resistors near LEDs with multimeter, and they also look like work (I thought that maybe one LED or diode burns).
So probably problem not in LEDs, then I explore PCB, and found few ICs, STM MCU — main MCU, Bluetooth ICs module on soldered top PCB, power management IC and in the center of board — 2 register shifters (maybe one shifter damaged with overcurrent strength? But how to test it then?).
So my question is, does anyone had such problem before? And what I can do to find what component is wrong and what prevents to work exactly half of LEDs? I have a multimeter, a soldering iron, lens some electric staff.



does anyone had such problem before ? ... how useful is a yes answer? ... please ask about the problem, not about people's experience

I suggest using your continuity tester to find out where the failing set of LED's traces lead. There's probably a common connection (or chip) for the half of the LED's that are failing. And my guess is your problem is going to be one chip. But it could be a loose connection. Also, start building a schematic, because without it, we can't really help you much.
