Help identify what IC is it?
help please identify what IC is it (or even manufacturer) ? (22C3TWB0c e3 and and few triangles logo)


We need more context. What kind of device is this? What are the dimension? Show more the surrounding circuit.

It is IC on the Keychron K3 Pro PCB size 5x5 mm
( here full PCB photo https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/717083/how-to-test-keychron-k3-pro-pcb-leds)

Found this post about the Keychron Q3 which has a very similar IC marked 21D2TWB0A, but I can't find anything about that one either. Probably a very niche Chinese/Taiwanese manufacturer or something custom for Keychron.

I see but sad, there no word about what it or where buy it.

If it is a programmable IC you can't buy it. A blank microcontroller etc will do you no good.
